Finding my Android app's file output when running on a Chromebook
I'm working on an app to capture information into files.
It runs well on my three android phones.
I can find the files on the phones.
I'm trying to get it running on my Chromebook (Acer 514).
I'm monitoring the log using:
adb logcat debug
My problem is, I can't find my files on the Chromebook.
When I run my app and save a file, the log tells me the file is at:
`/data/user/0/com.appname.capture/files/`

and I can find the files using Device File Explorer (in Android Dev Studio) at:
`/data/data/com.appname.capture/files/`

When I explore the device over USB, this dir shows up but is empty:
`...\Internal storage\Android\data\com.appname.capture\files\`

#1) Is there a way to "see" the files over USB?
#2) Where are the files on a Chromebook?
I'm using Kotlin in Android Development Studio (current).
I'm using
val outPath = filesDir
and then I add subdirs to create the output file name.
filesDir is from the java.io.File import, I think i remember seeing.
The files are there because I close the app and re-open it and it loads the files saved.
Thanks in advance.

I sincerely apologize for the formatting; this is my first post here.  I didn't know the # tag made the line a header...
